# remove extra network adapters

Tags: windows-10, networking, device-manager

I've several network adapters in device manager, I suppose majority of them is not needed.

I'd like to remove the extra ones, however I don't know how to remove only those which are really not needed.

I see only two connections being active in task manager, some are shown, but not traffic, some are even can't be selected.

Which adapters can I remove from device manager?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Cisco Any Connect, Hyper-V, Microsoft Adapters, Realtek, and WAN Miniport adapters are all legitimate. Do not remove these.

These adapters are required for the software they are associated with to work. Deleting the adapters will break the associated software.

PANGP and Zscaler are yours. You can likely remove these by uninstalling the device.

Do NOT remove other adapters you do not understand right away. They do not do any harm and they do not need to be removed.